# How do I get a list of distinct rows by who has both flag 1 and 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Users Sessions.
Columns - UserID, SessionID, Completed (bit).

I want to get the list of Users who has both Completed = 0 and Completed = 1

Comment: We need a sample data to work on it and a desired results, also it would be good if you provide what did you try to solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The query below will return the UserId has both the 0 and 1 of the Completed column entries.

```
SELECT UserId
FROM Users
WHERE Completed IN (0, 1)  
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Completed ) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select userid
from suers
group by users
having min(completed) = 0 and max(completed) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select distinct userid from sessions where completed=1
    Intersect
    Select distinct userid from sessions where completed=0
```

The intersect gets only users in both sets

Comment: Just code? Don't you think you should explain a bit what that code will do?